# How to display labels from many-to-many relationship in ArcGIS 10 using VB.NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-engine, vb.net, spatial-join

I have two tables in a geodatabase:

- parcel; and
- person

1 or + parcel, can have 1 or +  person (relationship is many-to-many)

Using VB.NET I can display all the parcel labelled with the "id" field (see picture on left).

What I want is to display the parcel with labels for the Names of their persons (see picture on right):

[image]

I think that I have to use join between two tables

I can get the name with this code

```
 Sub addNom()
        ' Open the origin and destination classes.
        Dim featureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace = CType(Sp, IFeatureWorkspace)
        Dim originClass As IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("parcelle")
        Dim destinationClass As IObjectClass = CType(featureWorkspace.OpenTable("personne"), IObjectClass)

        ' Create a memory relationship class factory and open a relationship class with it.
        Dim relClassFactoryType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeodatabase.MemoryRelationshipClassFactory")
        Dim memRelClassFactory As IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(relClassFactoryType), IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory)
        Dim memRelClass As IRelationshipClass = memRelClassFactory.Open("pll_personne", originClass, "id", _
                                                destinationClass, "id", "Contains", "Is in", esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToMany)

        ' Find the counties related to the state with an ObjectID of 1.
        Dim originFeature As IFeature = originClass.GetFeature(6)
        Dim relatedSet As ISet = memRelClass.GetObjectsRelatedToObject(originFeature)
        relatedSet.Reset()

        ' Iterate through the set while finding the names of the counties.
        Dim nameIndex As Integer = destinationClass.FindField("nom_fr")
        Dim setObject As Object = relatedSet.Next()
        While Not setObject Is Nothing
            Dim row As IRow = CType(setObject, IRow)
            Console.WriteLine("OID: {0}, NAME: {1}", row.OID, row.Value(nameIndex))
            setObject = relatedSet.Next()
        End While
    End Sub
```

The Question is:

**How  can I display the labels using this result?**

Comment: You could take a look at the AnnotationFeature object.  From what I know about it, the IAnnotationFeature interface lets you build your own annotation.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000nt000000 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000206000000